# A way to detect mouseenter vs touch click? How about using Modernizr?

Tags: mobile, hover, touch, mouselistener, modernizr

I need to find a way to know if a user has used mouse hover or touch click to show and hide different menu links.  What I want to do is this.

```
if(a user used a mouseenter or mouseleave){
       $("li.mobile-show > a").hide();
       $("div.hover-over").hover(function(){
            $(".hover-dropdown", this).children().slideToggle(); 
        });
}
else if(a user used touch click){
        $("li.mobile-show > a").show();     
        $("div.hover-over").click(function(){
            $(".hover-dropdown", this).children().toggle(); 
        });
}
```

I tried `Modernizr.mq('only all and (min-width: 768px)')` to see if I can separate the table & mobile device vs computer screen, but it didn't work for large tablet devices that show the desktop view but only can use the touch feature.  Help~!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old trouble. Unfortunately there is no way. Not with `Modernizr`, not with anything.

- Desktop browsers (at least major ones) has `ontouchstart` (`'ontouchstart' in window`) and whole **Touch Events API**.
- Mobile browsers emulates mouse events.
- making conclusions based on device width/dimensions is also prone to errors: many tablets has 1280, 1300 and more pixels width

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! Listen for the touch start event as well as mouse enter. In case of mobile touch click, both will be fired but touch start will be fired first. In case of desktop mouse enter, only the mouse enter will be fired. In touch start, set a timestamp of touch. Then, at mouse enter, check if the timestamp is set and if it's been less than a small amount of time (say 100ms). If so, do not take the action you normally take in mouse enter. That seems to be working for me.